# How will we be handling the Shia and Sunni difference?

Tags: discussion, shia-sunni

Shia and Sunni Islam can at times have a huge "view difference". How will the moderators, community and the rest manage this?

Comment: Just FYI for the group to consider... http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/504/131 is an example of an answer with undertones of a "Shia" belief that some questioners might want to know is a distinctly Shia belief and might be worth pointing out to readers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the differences are in belief; less are in action. I don't see any reason to distinguish unless the question specifically asks about one vs. the other.

Tagging would also help. What I'm proposing therefore is:

- Most questions don't distinguish between Shi'a and Sunni
- Questions that are specifically about either can be tagged as such (e.g. what is the view of Shi'a/Sunni Islam on ...)

Comment: +1 - there shouldn't be much friction as long as answers are properly sourced and clearly explain the conditions and viewpoints under which the answer is valid.

Comment: I don't think we should allow Sunni/Shi'a questions at all. Everything should be general. The Quran says, don't divide yourselves into sects, and this is promoting the sects...

Comment: @Dynamic you can't ignore it. Some people quote Shi'a imams, some quote sunni imams, etc. We can be respectfully tolerant of all opinions.

Comment: @ashes999 What about the people that don't categorize themselves. Period. They go by the Prophet Muhammad's (S) Sunnah and the Quran.

Comment: @Dynamic there can't be many of those and they must be Mujtahid otherwise how will they derive rulings if they are not doing takleed.

Comment: @Dynamic those people are sunnis. They follow the "sunnah" or Rasulullah.

Answer (score 9):

I think allowing both to answer is fine, a question can have two answers from both point of views as long as the answers are directed to answer the OP's question and not to reply to the other answer of the opposite denomination.

Answer (score 2):

Its quite healthy to have opinions from both sides. We get to learn about each other. It would be good to always specify from whom one is quoting from so that the reader is made aware about which sect the answer is from.

Having said that, such questions have been seen to always attract downvotes from the opposite sect. We should somehow stop this bias.