# Shia/Sunni referring questions

Tags: discussion, shia-sunni

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How will we be handling the Shia and Sunni difference?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-will-we-be-handling-the-shia-and-sunni-difference)

Well [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce-sunni) states that he wants to know about the divorce the Sunni way.
Well in Islam there is no Shia no Sunni no Shafi no Hanafee so why should we follow this here.
We will run a vote count to see who all agree to this or disagree. You can also post any extra arguments needed below.

Comment: @Caleb im sayin to completely eradicate the use of shia/sunni not just handle them differently

Comment: why in Islam there is no Shia no Sunni. its like to say there is no sun in the sky. Niak is a wahhabi and although says no shia no sunni but in fact promotes wahhabism. also prophet said Muslims wil be 73 sect after me. do you disagree prophet?

Comment: @Ahmadi give a refernce plz. you might be right but i have never heard of `73 sects`

Comment: @Ashu this is a very famous Hadith and accepted as authentic by both shia and sunni. sorry now I have not ref. but I am sure it can be found by googeling

Answer (score 6):

The OP is asking for knowledge from a particular viewpoint and I don't see anything wrong with that. There are different schools of jurisprudence in Islam and the person asking the question might be only interested in knowing about a particular viewpoint. I don't see any problem with the question.

There are [different schools in Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_schools_and_branches) and answers to jurisprudence questions can heavily depend on the school and scholar, there is not a general consensus among Muslims and Islamic scholars regarding the answer to these questions. A person who is following say Hanafi School might not be interested in answers from say Shia school. Even finer levels of scope should be permitted since one might follow the rulings of a particular Muslim scholar.

(On the other hand I find your post problematic since it assumes your beliefs as the base for the discussion "Well in Islam there is no Shia no Sunni no Shafai no Hanafee [...]" which is demonstrably incorrect. You are assuming a particular view and using as a base for restricting what questions can asked which is unhelpful IMHO.)

Comment: +1 "On the other hand I find your post problematic since it assumes your beliefs as the base for the discussion"