# Don't make assumptions about the beliefs of any user by just reading the post they author

Tags: discussion, faq-content, philosophy

This thing is poisonous. I have tried to diffuse a whole load of this responsibility for a long time now but it was futile. I'll try to address it.

**The poison:** *"That user is of sect X/ X-ian"*

Why does it even matter? How is that even important for this site?

On Islam.SE too, [*the emphasis is on a post, not a user*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124599/221866). So if the post doesn't meet the criteria set forth by the community, so be it. Why even bring the notion of the sect that the author of the post belongs to? *It's baffling and disappointing.*

If you think the action that was taken on the post wasn't fair then make your cogent defense and bring it on meta. Fight your case based on the merits of that post and let the community decide. **That's it.** Nothing more nothing less. The community shall decide.

**Don't make any assumption about the sect of the author/user just by looking their at posts and the views presented in it.** If a user happens to know about a particular subject of Islam that happens belong to Y school of belief, would you be go out and declare him/her Y-ian? *You should not.*

Even if the author happens to declare their sect, it still shouldn't have **any** influence on the way that post is treated and judgments, on that posts (not the authors) merits, are passed.

So

- fight your case based on the merits of the post
- be cogent (it's kind of unfortunate for some that it has to be in English only)
- your/their sect has zero influence on any aspect of how this site it run. If it has (*proof required*)? Then there is something terribly wrong which has to be addressed.
- if you think you were mistreated, bring your case to meta. Be objective about it. Bring your proof. Be specific. Be to the point.
- your expertise and knowledge is important to this site
- ask the community why a particular action was taken, what is the problem and how shall it be treated

We want users who know about the subject. Not who believe in the subject. We don't assume anything about any user's belief nor has it got anything to do with this site.

*You may pour in now.*

Comment: +1 Very clear. Thanks for posting.

Comment: `That's it. Nothing more nothing less. The community shall decide.`  Thank you, exactly my point

Comment: Oh, yeah. Likewise I approve what you remarked and it indeed can be deemed as a significant and admirable point what the questioner (and the positive comments) remarked. Hopefully it be performed in pracitce (as @Medi saif mentioned that "in practice..."

Comment: I understand your point. But I have one tiny concern (Maybe because I misunderstood the point of this post) and that is: We have to consider user's sect if we want to answer his question. Most people look specifically  for their own school of thought rulings. Example: If a Sunni asks about 'Divoce' issue and what are the rulings, then if Gair Muqalid or Shia hazrat answer, it will confuse the user. So they have to specify that these answers/rulings are according to these sects and let us know your sect so we can dig up rulings according to it else it will only confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

That's a fine statement and a good guideline, but in practice hard to follow!

Please don't get me wrong I mean the practice and what I do see here on the site is totally different. You may read my point of view on sectarianism [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/947/should-we-have-a-new-site-specific-for-sunni-and-shia/1728#1728).

The problem is or could be:

- If a Sunni (I guess one only need to check the profile to know the tendencies, or the quoted sources etc.) questions about a Shi’a ruling and vice versa or a Shi’a questions why Sunni don't have this or that!

It is hard for pure sectarians not to down or up vote (and in cases i wouldn't exclude myself, even if my primary goal is to find truth everywhere and i do respect all humans -including Muslims of any sect ;)-).

- An other point is that some of the Posts are clearly asking for a Shi’a or Sunni view which makes or emphasizes a clear separation between Muslims. I still hope that brothers and sisters of all sects answer my question, I'd be glad to hear/read/listen to an other point of view ... I want to learn not to stay still and cramped and restricted in my own points of view!

Please note i don't want to say that this is bad, but again pure sectarians may react as described and we can't stop that!

- Also in practice you see questions asked by a person of either of the sects, saying Sunni and Shi’a view welcome, but once an answer of the "opposite" sect comes you see it down voted... that is not constructive at all!

I came across lots of posts that are great questions and have got many down votes, all i can contribute is up-voting them and therefore I'd ask anybody to read the questions and answers and **vote for the content** not anything else!